# How I can disable copy paste in an input box in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have input box, I don't want user to copy paste into the input box  '-'(minus) , '.'(decimal) value

Comment: do you want user when pasting something like `123-4`, input value will be `1234`, or block the paste altogether?

Comment: block the paste when it contains minus or decimal

Answer (score 1):

You can use onCopy, onPaste, onCut event to disable action.

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

<TextField
      value={val}
      onCut={handleChange}
      onCopy={handleChange}
      onPaste={handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

below an implementation blocking paste with given conditions:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const onPaste = (e) => {
    const paste = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
    if (paste.match(/[-\.]/)) return
    setValue(paste)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onPaste={onPaste} />
      {value}
    </div>
  );
}
```